# Выделить ещё ядер на обработку сети(sysctl)

Tags: linux, сеть, kernel

При нагрузке на сеть(много соединений и дудос) у меня нагружается только ядро №5.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Как можно распределить нагрузку на все ядра?(настраивал sysctl, irqbalance нет)

Comment: чем Вы нагружаете сеть? Что такое "дудос"?

Comment: @KoVadim, просто обычная нагрузка

Comment: может у Вас приложение, которое не умеет нагружать все ядра.

Comment: @KoVadim, это линукс

Comment: это понятно. я даже могу сказать, что на картинке запущен htop. Но вопроса это не отменяет

Comment: @KoVadim, ну, это kernel поток отвечающий за обработку трафика. Мне надо его распоточить на 4 потока

Comment: @Cus я ниже написал решение вашей проблемы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для начала, тебе нужно узнать, работает ли на твоем сервере механизм ядра, называющийся RPS:

```
watch -n1 cat /proc/softirqs
```

Если NET_RX и NET_TX прерывания идут только на одно ядро, значит RPS не включен, и его необходимо сконфигурировать, с помощью установки битовых масок в:

```
/sys/class/net/DEVICE/queues/QUEUE/rps_cpus
```

Битовые маски, в HEX формате означают, на каких cpu будут обрабатываться сетевые прерывания, и для каждой системы они будут разные.

Статья с примером установки таких масок:
https://habrahabr.ru/company/flant/blog/332432/

Подробнее об RPS можно прочитать тут:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.13/Documentation/networking/scaling.txt#L138-L164